# What is a pseudo-random integer?

Tags: c, random

I am reading a C book.  In the description of the `rand()` function, they say:

> `rand` returns a pseudo-random integer in the range `0` to `RAND_MAX`.  `RAND_MAX` is implementation dependent but at least `32767`.

I don't understand; what is a "pseudo-random integer"?

Thanks.

Comment: I'll add a free hint to whatever Mitch wrote you. The next time you see a word you don't know, try to google for "(myword) wiki". 50% of the time It Just Works!

Comment: This [page](http://tinyurl.com/lh3jpk) might help.

Comment: @Mehrdad Exceptional! I didn't know that site!!! My new favourite :-)

Comment: Note also a lack of precision in language, which is common and rarely matters, but confuses concepts. There's no such thing as "a random number". There are such things as (in mathematics) "a random variable" and (in practical programming) "a random number generator". The integer value actually returned by `rand` when you call it once, is no different from any other integer with the same value. It isn't "pseudo-random" on its own: "pseudo-randomness" is a property of a sequence of many values returned from many calls to `rand`. Read all answers with that caveat.

Comment: See Knuth, TAOCP Vol.2, Chapter 3 introduction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Informally, a pseudorandom number is a number that isn't truly random, but is "random enough" for most purposes.

Computers are inherently deterministic devices.  The processor executes specific commands in a specific order, and programs control how the processor does so.  Consequently, it's hard for programs to generate random numbers because no deterministic process can create a random number.  Thus what many programs do is use a *pseudorandom number generator*, which is a function that produces numbers according to some deterministic formula that appear to be random but actually are not.  Most programming languages provide some sort of pseudorandom number generator for general programming use, and when true randomness isn't needed they work just fine.

However, they have their limitations.  In cryptographic settings, in many cases true randomness is required in order to prevent attackers from guessing the workings of a system and compromising it, for example.  In this case, it is possible to get truly random numbers by using specialized hardware that can amplify background noise or use quantum effects.  This sort of randomness is extremely hard to generate, though, and so it's not commonly used unless absolute unpredictability is required.

Comment: I'll add this, because random numbers CAN be generated by computers. Computers aren't deterministic, otherwhise they wouldn't break at random times :-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

Comment: @xanatos- True, I was oversimplifying things a bit.  You can measure things like clock skew etc. to build up an entropy accumulator.

Answer (score 3):

From wiki entry  : [Pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

> A pseudorandom number generator
>   (PRNG), also known as a deterministic
>   random bit generator (DRBG), is an
>   algorithm for generating **a sequence of
>   numbers that approximates the
>   properties of random numbers**.

In other words, its approximately random (to a known extent), but not truly random in the sense of random noise from a physical source.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the number may seems to be random but the truth is computer can't generate a truly random number, it works out a number based on a logic which tends to be random.

Like observing time difference in keystrokes, and then using it as just an input in calculating a number. Such things combined with several other inputs tend to give random numbers but in reality its just an algorithm which tends to give random numbers. If the same conditions are matched, it will give the same number.

Answer (score 2):

To add some pedantry to the other correct answers that you've already received, there really is no such thing as a "pseudorandom integer" (or for that matter, a random integer).  This is the point that [John von Neumann](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann) was making in his famous quote (which is usually misleading abbreviated to just the first sentence):

> "Any one who considers arithmetical
>   methods of producing random digits is,
>   of course, in a state of sin. For, as
>   has been pointed out several times,
>   there is no such thing as a random
>   number — there are only methods to
>   produce random numbers, and a strict
>   arithmetic procedure of course is not
>   such a method"

Consider the number 7.  Is it a random integer?  If it is, is it a pseudorandom integer or a true random integer?  What about the number -10?  Clearly these questions don't make sense ([obligatory link to xkcd 221](http://xkcd.com/221/)).

So, as others have pointed out, what the book actually means is that the number is generated by a pseudorandom (i.e. deterministic) number generator as opposed to being obtained from a truly random sequence.  There are several different pseudorandom number generator algorithms and the best ones generate output that is [statistically](http://www.stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/) indistinguishable from a true random sequence.

Answer (score 1):

It means that it generates a number sequence that exhibits the properties of a random number in terms of distribution, but which is mathematically generated and deterministic in its output for any particular *seed* value.

You can see this by creating a program that uses such a function to generate a short sequence, and observing that each time you run it it generates the same sequence.  This option surprises the unsuspecting, but is also quite a useful property in testing code.  When a less predictable sequence is required, one normally initialised the PRNG with a *seed* value that is itself unpredictable, often derived from the current system time, since it is not normally predictable when a program will be started.

Pseudo random number generators are not normally suitable for security applications such as data encryption, or on-line gambling applications, where their ultimate predictability could be a serious weakness.

Answer (score 0):

In most computers, a random number is considered psuedorandom because it is not completely random.

pseudo=fake

Basically, the current time is used to generate a random number, so it can be predicted what number will be generated initially, and for most applications, this is fine.

Comment: @Mitch I corrected the reply myself and voted it because it basically reply the question with fewer words than others.

Comment: Pseudo *is* fake, *not* almost. A PRNG isn't "almost" random, it *simulates* randomness by producing sequences that have certain properties of sequences of true random samples. But they lack the crucial defining property of randomness, which is non-reproducibility. The prefix "pseudo-" does occasionally mean "almost" in English, but IMO not in this case.

Comment: Also, `rand` doesn't use the current time to generate a random number. Users might call `srand` with a seed based on the time, in which case the output of `rand` would be based on the time. Or they could call it with a seed based on the weather, in which case the output of `rand` would be based on the weather. That's up to them.

Comment: @user623879: I've edited it back, although you could probably have done that yourself.