# What is pseudo random?

Tags: python, random

I was reading the docs for the random module and noticed it said pseudo random and thought doesnt pseudo mean False so i was wondering what it means when it says that

For Example:

```
import random

print random.randint(1,2)
print random.randint(1,3)
```

does this still mean that the first print statement has a 50% chance of printing 1 and a 50% chance of printing 2

and that the second print statement has a 33% chance of printing one and a 33% chance of printing 2 etc.

if not then how are the pseudo random numbers generated ?

Comment: Can anything truly be random? I think similar questions have been asked before though.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness

Comment: @wazy http://i.stack.imgur.com/tsNeV.jpg

Comment: @NullUserException Thanks for the laugh. Should of made that one of the answers heh.

Comment: @NullUserException hahah pretty good explanation!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a pseudo-random integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209841/what-is-a-pseudo-random-integer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To produce true randomness requires specialized hardware that measures random events, such as radioactive decay (random) or brownian motion (also essentially random). Most computers obviously don't have these, so instead you have to use a really complex, evenly distributed, hard to predict 'pseudorandom' algorithm that starts with a number determined by, for example, the current timestamp. Such algorithms are plenty good enough for standard use cases needing 'randomness' as long as you're careful to not seed two random number generators with the same timestamp (start them at the same time on different threads, for example), which will make them do identical things. A common example of such a random number generator is Mersenne Twister: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister

A site that offers truly random values, explains a lot about randomness and pseudorandomness and has some yummy statistics about its randomness: http://www.random.org/ (see Learn More and Statistics) (It actually seems that it relies on measuring tiny fluctuations in a chaotic system, e.g. atmospheric noise, but the statistics show that it is so much like true randomness you can't tell it apart!)

Comment: that makes since but say i did `random.randint(1,2)` will be the same as flipping a coin?

Comment: @Christian Careaga What kind of coin are we talking about? Are we talking about physically flipping a physical coin in real life, which is biased by the weight of the two sides, how the person decides to flip it, what side it starts on, the wind, the air pressure, etc? Or an idealized truely random coin which is always random and unpredictable in what it returns? Because it is not like either, but it ATTEMPTS to be like the latter, as close as you can without having a true randomness source.

Comment: it might or not be, depending on algorithm you are using.

Comment: @Patashu Maybe radioactive decay isn't truly random either, it could be that we just can't predict it yet.

Comment: Ok I see so basically nothing is truly random its more of an idea so pseudo random is the closest we can get?

Comment: @NullUserException Radioactive decay is truly random, or at least cannot be predicted by a system of local hidden variables. Start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell's_theorem

Comment: @Christian Careaga No, true randomness exists. Many things in quantum physics are truly random. However, consumer PCs do not have any equipment that can be used to measure a source of true randomness. So we write pseudorandom number generators that can run on any computer to give us an appearance of randomness.

Comment: Alright thanks so much for explaining that slowly to me sorry i can be kinda slow

Comment: An very simple example of a pseudo random algorithm would be: `def prng(x): return (x * 214013 + 2531011) % math.pow(2, 32)` - where x is your seed. You will notice the same seed produces the same result.

Comment: @invert: there is even [nothing obviously wrong with the prng looking at its bitmap](https://www.wakari.io/sharing/bundle/jfs/Test%20PRNG%20using%20gray%20bitmap) (inspired by [Simple Visual Analysis from random.org](http://www.random.org/analysis/#visual)).

Comment: Whoa that is pretty neat, thanks for that @J.F.Sebastian! Fascinating... For reference, this is known as a [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)